# PHP - Check if column contains a string?

Tags: php, string

What I want to is create an API using PHP which will allow my program to check if a column within a table contains a certain string.

For example,
say I enter

```
www.mywebsite.com/api.php?word="ANY WORD"
```

The script would echo true or false if the database contained that word or not.

I am using a MySQL database and I have no idea how to go about this.

---

```
<?php

try {
  $username = '******';
  $password = '******';
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=******;dbname=**********', $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {

echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();

}

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wordlist WHERE words LIKE :aword');
  $stmt->execute(array('aword' => "%{$_GET['word']}%"));
  return ($stmt->fetchColumn() != 0);
?>
```

What did I do wrong? I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ***** on line 11

Comment: a mysql [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) query would be a good place to start

Comment: By "a column ... contains", do you mean that the entire value would be "ANY WORD" or it could be within a longer piece of text like "This text has ANY WORD in the middle."?

Comment: fulltext would be overkill when checking for the existence a 'single word'

Answer (score 1):

You need something along the lines of:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `atable` WHERE `afield` LIKE :aword');
$stmt->execute(array('aword' => "%{$_GET['word']}%"));
return ($stmt->fetchColumn() != 0);
```

In the example we search for the word in the GET parameter inside the `afield` database field inside the `atable` table.

Comment: +1 for PDO, and prepared statements.

Comment: Please look at my new updated post.

Comment: @Bizzet, you need to put all the lines inside the try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the word in the url and use it to query your database.

for your example: www.mywebsite.com/api.php?word="ANY WORD"

```
$keyword = $_GET["word"]
```

now you can create an sql statement with one or multiple LIKEs.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 LIKE("%".$keyword."%") OR colomn2 LIKE("%".$keyword."%")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Be cautious when writing code like this, users tend to copy paste answers, and this is vulnerable to SQL injections.